# Magento 2 layout XML <move /> performance

Tags: magento2, layout

I was just wondering if anyone knows about negative performance impacts of multiple `<move />` statements in a theme's layout XML files.
Sometimes the `<move />` statement is even in the same file that the element that gets repositioned: it gets defined inside some block or container, and afterward moved somewhere else.

I often see XML files in a theme with like 20 `<move />` statements per file, which results in 100+ `<move />` statements per theme.

I was not able to find the place in the source code where they are handled, so I "assume" for the generation of the "whole" layout XML, that...

- ...it's easy when `<referenceBlock />` or `<referenceContainer />` is used because a lot of the structure is already present in the XML
- ...it's expensive when `<move />` statements are used because Magento has to parse the XML tree over and over again and again

It would be nice if someone could point me where I can find this in the code, or even had some performance benchmarks or experience to share.